# Internet timing out through VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a VPN (OpenVPN) for my home network, I can connect to it and VNC/RDP/SSH to any of my systems and reach websites with out any issues expect when I went to Tampa International Airport. I VPN'd back to help my wife with something on the computer, but for some reason I couldn't load any web pages from my system (the VNC'd system reach websites fine). I could connect to all my systems with out any issues, but have not had that issue before. I tried PIA VPN and I could connect to any web sites with out any issues, confused on why PIA's VPN didn't have that issue.

I was hoping someone might be able to explain this.

Comment: Search for `split tunneling`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping if someone might know how they are doing it (cause I thought PIA uses port 1194 like what I'm using for my OpenVPN) and if there is a reason why.